# ruby2exe does not include require files if they under if statement

Tags: ruby

I am using 2 set of scripts for soap communication, inside they are identical classes and variables therefore when using the main script I need to put condition.

if A
require A.rb

if B 
require B.rb

The problem is that the ruby2exe does not include these script when compiling the main script.

If have put the 2 require on the top of the file it does not work but then the main script confuse between the classes in the two files.

Idea how to solve it ?

Thanks
Eran

Comment: what version of Ruby do you use ?

Comment: 1.8, I did a short test with different script and I saw that if I write simple script it does to effect the require even if I am putting it inside if statement the problem is with long script or maybe because it is inside the class not sure..

Comment: the require are starting at line 520, maybe there is param I can configure to for the ruby2exe to read it as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to include both at the beginning so the compiler picks them up, later at line +520 you do the include again, i presume the last included file will be what is used.
Also try the [ocra](http://ocra.rubyforge.org/) compiler which is more recent then ruby2exe.

Comment: I tried to put both the required in the top of the file I got error message when execute the script manually superclass mismatch for class <class name>  I wanted to use OCRA but it is windows only support and I am using linux